# Google Calendar API - set guest can modify to true

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-calendar-api

I'm using the google calendar api for a calendar web app. My app allows users to create and modify calendar events and it syncs these changes with user's google calendars. I recently noticed that when one user creates an event and invites another user to that event, that invited user can only change the topic of the event for his/her calendar, not for all the other participants. I would like one user's changes to be reflected on the google calendar's of all the other participants. Google Calendar's website provides an option for allowing guests to modify the event: [image]

but I wasn't able to find where I could specify this option in the [google calendar api](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/). How can I use the gcal api to set guestsCanModify to true when an event is created?

Comment: Hey, were you able to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

2021 update:
Just set the **guestsCanModify** to **true** in Event object
https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events

Answer (score 0):

That is probably some Google magic in the Google Calendar website.  If you check the documentation for [Events.insert](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert#request-body) There is nothing about granting attendees permissions on the event.    It would appear that you can only add a [user](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/acl/insert#request-body) to a calendar but not limit their permissions in anyway with regard to events.

However I think that is a new feature which makes me think it might be something they will be adding to the API in the future.  It would be nice if they did.